# Replace in python the "\" of a Windows path with "/"

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I want to use a path in python but python doesn't understand usual path with a "\".
So I decided to fix it with the method ".replace" and "/". The problem is that when I use the method ".replace", it doesn't read "\" as a character... How do do it ?
If I can improve this question by any way, let me know !

```
raw_path=(str(input("please write down the exact path")))+"/"
raw_path.replace("\","/")
```

Comment: Classic XY problem. Just use a raw string literal (`r'C:\now\backslash\can\be\used'`)

Comment: Do you have an exemple? I don't really fully understand ? Thanks for your fast answer

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace !! Works perfectly!

Comment: For reading `\ ` as a character, you need to escape it, `'\\'`. DeepSpace's fix is the 99% solution, but if a string ever does need to end with a backslash it won't work (because the only character `\ ` escapes in a raw string is the quote character itself, so it can't actually end with a backslash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I've used the solution of DeepSpace for another part of my code and instead used the solution of  ShadowRanger.
The code that I use now is:

```
raw_path=(str(input("please write down the exact path")))+"/"
raw_path.replace("\\","/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths in python work best if you use '\\' instead of '\' or '/'

eg.

```
C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop
```

So for your case, you can use:

```
raw_path = raw_path.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

or

```
raw_path = raw_path.replace('/', '\\\\')
```

if the text you get has '/' instead of '\'